# jquery datepicker control for each listbox item

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listbox

I want to have jquery datepicker control for each listitem in the listbox so that user can set the different date for each listitem. any help would be great. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your list items should belong to one class, say "datetime"

**EDITED:**

```
<li class="datetime">1</li>
<li class="datetime">2</li>
<li class="datetime">3</li>

$(function() {

  $('li').each(function () {
    $(this).append('<input class="datetime"></input>');
  });

  $('.datetime').datepicker();

});
```

Comment: i tried this already but its not working as datepicker need input field. thx for ur reply

Comment: i have tried again without any luck. plz see the following code

Comment: <select size="8" name="Base" multiple="multiple" id="Base">
 <option value="147" class="datepicker">ERP</option>
 <option value="150" class="datepicker">PIC status</option>
 <option value="160" class="datepicker">TEST</option>
</select>

Comment: $('option.datepicker').each(
                                function () {
                                    
                                    $(this).append('<input class="datetime"></input>');
                                }
                            );

                            $(".datepicker").datepicker();